# Jwplayer plugin gapro-2 throws Object Expected issue in IE-7/8 on closing/refresh window

Tags: jwplayer

Gapro2 issue on following line.

function g(){try{window.attachEvent("onbeforeunload",function(u){i()})}catch(t){}

when above event is triggered it gives issue at last line of following code snippet

//jwplayer.js

```
if(typeof jwplayer=="undefined"){var jwplayer=function(a){if(jwplayer.api){return        jwplayer.api.selectPlayer(a)}};var $jw=jwplayer;jwplayer.version="5.10.2295";jwplayer.vid=document.createElement("video");jwplayer.audio=document.createElement("audio");jwplayer.source=document.createElement("source");(function(b){b.utils=function(){};b.utils.typeOf=function(d){var c=typeof d;if(c==="object"){if(d){if(d instanceof Array){c="array"}}else{c="null"}}return c};b.utils.extend=function(){var c=b.utils.extend["arguments"];if(c.length>1){for(var e=1;e<c.length;e++){for(var d in c[e]){c[0][d]=c[e][d]
```

it occurs when i press refresh/close in IE-8 or ie-7.

it does not occur if first i play video then press refresh.

Exact Error: "Object Expected"

Stack Trace:

JScript anonymous function

> m //gapro

i //gapro

JScript anonymous function

m method calls n.currentItem.. which is always null, if video play button was not clicked.

any workaround of it?

Thx